# Maven - pointing to a *single* repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I've got a Nexus Maven repository that I want to be the *one and only repository* used by my projects.

Per the [Nexus documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html), To solve this problem I should change my local .m2/settings.xml.

Changing my settings.xml to solve this problem isn't a good practice, as it's not portable across different developer machines / CI servers.

What I want to do is change my global parent pom to say "use this and only this repository for all projects that use me as a parent."  How can I do that?  I see that I can add my repository as *one* of the repositories that are checked, but not the *only* repository.  I tried cutting and pasting the ['mirror' section of the settings file](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) to my pom, but 'mirror' is not allowed there.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak Nexus' instructions of modifying your $HOME/.m2/settings.xml.  Have a networked settings file that refers to Nexus.  This settings file should be used by all developers (and your CI server).

How do all developers refer to this one settings file?

There are a couple of ways of skinning that cat.

Option 1: Alias your Maven command.
   On UNIX: `alias mvn=mvn -s /networked/path/to/settings.xml`
   ON Windows: Open mvn.bat.  Find mvn invocation and alter it similarly

Option 2: Home/settings linked to networked location
  ON UNIX: `cd $HOME; rm settings.xml;ln -s /networked/path/to/settings.xml settings.xml`
   ON Windows: I don't know the equivalent foo for symbolic linking

Comment: Thanks Sri, think this is the best option

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a "standard" Maven install for all developers, you can change `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`

Otherwise, you're out of luck with anything short of an intelligent network proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to configure the `<repositories>` element in your pom?

```
<project>
  ...
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>my-internal-site</id>
        <url>http://myserver/repo</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
  ...
</project>
```

More information and details can be found at the [Maven Internal Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html#Internal_Repositories) page.

Comment: Unf. this only adds the repository, it doesn't make it the only repository available.